# Preterite vs Imperfect with Poder

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto

Entonces, decidimos llamar por teléfono a un amigo que, afortunadamente, estaba en casa, por lo que **pudo** venir a recogernos.

Why use the preterite instead of imperfect?

Isn't the ability to do something uncountable in terms of how much time you are capable of doing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Poder* in the imperfect merely expresses the ability to do something.  It doesn't express whether it actually happened or not.  So if I say, *Ayer podía ir al cine*, all you know is that I had the time off and the money to go to the movie.  Maybe I went, maybe I didn't — neither is implied.  In the negative, *Ayer no podía ir al cine*, though, we know I didn't.

On the other hand, in the preterite, *poder* expresses a bit more.  If you say *Ayer pude ir al cine*, you were able to *and you did*.  In the negative, if you say *Ayer no pude ir al cine*, you are indicating that you attempted to go, but failed to, and therefore *you did not* go.

Comment: Add to this, the negative, no podía ir al cine, implies that no attempt was made.